# Hide <div> element when 'ng-controller' is also assigned

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide an entire `<div>` using `ng-if`, but my below code is not working, presumably because `ng-if` and `ng-controller` are assigned to the same `<div>`.

If I move the `ng-if` condition to any element within the parent `<div>` then it works fine, but I'd rather not do this because -

1. I'd have a superfluous DOM element visible, but with nothing inside of it.
2. I'd potentially have to include the same `ng-if` condition multiple times.

My question therefore is how can I hide the entire `<div>`, rather than just the elements within?

```
<div id="sidebar-recent" data-ng-controller="closestCtrl" data-ng-if="closestStation != false">

    <h3>Closest Station</h3>

    <ul class="stations-list" data-ng-model="closestStationsList">
        <li class="station" data-ng-click="selectStation(recentStation)">
            {{ closestStation.name }} ({{ (closestStation.code | uppercase) }})
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Here is the relevant JS -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('closestCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.closestStation = false;
});
```

Comment: I don't think they work alongside each other, because of scope requirements. I might be wrong about these specific two, but I'm sure it's correct for `ng-switch[-when|-default]` and `ng-include`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `ng-hide` or `ng-show` instead.

The difference between those and `ng-if` is, that the latter removes the element from the DOM, and the former only hides the element using style rules.

Comment: @Dieterg perhaps if you only look at the literal question in the title. If you read the question posed in the body, he wants to know how to hide the div, and doesn't restrict this to using ng-if only.

Comment: Thanks, `ng-show` and `ng-hide` allow me to achieve what I require.  You are quite correct in that I am not beholden to `ng-if`, hiding the DOM element as opposed to removing it is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove the whole div? It won't work If you are using ng-if you are actually removing the element from DOM. So the controller scope will be also removed. I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a another one `div` only for controller. It will solve your problem very easy... don't think too much..

Something like

```
<div data-ng-controller="closestCtrl">
<div id="sidebar-recent"  data-ng-if="closestStation != false">

    <h3>Closest Station</h3>

    <ul class="stations-list" data-ng-model="closestStationsList">
        <li class="station" data-ng-click="selectStation(recentStation)">
            {{ closestStation.name }} ({{ (closestStation.code | uppercase) }})
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did think of this, but as mentioned in my question - "I'd have a superfluous DOM element visible, but with nothing inside of it."  So while yes it would work, I was looking for a desirable alternative. Thanks any way.